# Runtime Error: Syntax error in Java Script in clean Basic MVC 4 ASP.NET Project

Tags: c#, javascript, internet-explorer, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to ASP.NET and I created MVC 4 ASP .NET project. It runs in a browser but I get those errors below and I don't get why is it so.

`Błąd czasu wykonywania kodu JavaScript` means `Runtime Error Java Script`.

```
 'iexplore.exe' (Script): Loaded 'Script Code (Windows Internet Explorer)'. 
    Exception was thrown at line 5302, column 6 in http://localhost:6468/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js
    0x800a139e - Błąd czasu wykonywania kodu JavaScript: SyntaxError
    Exception was thrown at line 37, column 60610 in http://localhost:3176/d36ef192c476437f94f058c98480760b/browserLink
    0x800a139e - Błąd czasu wykonywania kodu JavaScript: SyntaxError
    Exception was thrown at line 37, column 60451 in http://localhost:3176/d36ef192c476437f94f058c98480760b/browserLink
    0x800a139e - Błąd czasu wykonywania kodu JavaScript: SyntaxError
    Exception was thrown at line 37, column 60451 in http://localhost:3176/d36ef192c476437f94f058c98480760b/browserLink
    0x800a139e - Błąd czasu wykonywania kodu JavaScript: SyntaxError
    Exception was thrown at line 37, column 60451 in http://localhost:3176/d36ef192c476437f94f058c98480760b/browserLink
    0x800a139e - Błąd czasu wykonywania kodu JavaScript: SyntaxError
    Exception was thrown at line 37, column 60451 in http://localhost:3176/d36ef192c476437f94f058c98480760b/browserLink
    0x800a139e - Błąd czasu wykonywania kodu JavaScript: SyntaxError
    The thread 0x1324 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
    The thread 0x11f8 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
    The thread 0x954 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
```

_Layout.cshtml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1>ASP.NET MVC MUSIC STORE</h1>
        <ul id="navlist">
            <li class="first"><a href="/" id="current">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Store/">Store</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    @RenderBody()

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

`http://localhost:3176/d36ef192c476437f94f058c98480760b/browserLink`:

**line 37 col 60541:**

```
{return w.apply(f,x.call(m.querySelectorAll(n),0)),f}catch(p){}finally{k||d.removeAttribute("id")}}
```

Comment: Line 37. Why don't you tell us what that exact line is?

Comment: @Yoda Is this a joke? With that rep you should know how to ask. To solve some syntax error, the original code really is needed, not a bunch of error stack. What comes to line 37, it probably lacks `try` and has an extra `}` at the end of it, though this is just speculation, since who knows what you really have.

Comment: @Teemu This is totally new technology for me(Java Script and ASP.NET). I have not write a single line in Java Script in this project nor anywhere else. I don't even now which source file I should look for it. I only created a controller and a View to it and added the sth in html -> in OP.

Answer (score 1):

Answered a similar question over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30363282/2048857).  Reposting here.

> Those are handled exceptions, correct?  If so, you can safely ignore
>   all of the JavaScript Syntax "Errors" in your Output window.  The
>   jQuery team finds it acceptable to use handled Exceptions for logic
>   flow.  Yes, this decision makes debugging your application through VS
>   more difficult.  It clouds up the Output window.
>
> For more information check this [jQuery ticket 14123](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14123).

Comment: They were gone after reinstall of the system and reinstalling whole VS2013 Ultimate with Update 4.