# Lot of jquery Exceptions in correct or clean MVC 4 projects

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

Does not matter what project I download if it will be MVC Music Store, Ode to Food from Pluralsight or even in clean project I get lot of runtime exceptions because of syntax error somewhere in JavaScript code. Those files are hundreds of thousands characters long and are automatically generated I have nothing to do with them.

Is there a possiblity of having wrong or unstable JavaScript or something else installed? I have full VS 2013 Ultimate:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013
Version 12.0.30501.00 Update 2
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.51641

Installed Version: Ultimate

Architecture and Modeling Tools   06181-004-0451047-02312
Microsoft Architecture and Modeling Tools
    
UML® and Unified Modeling Language™ are trademarks or registered trademarks of the Object Management Group, Inc. in the United States and other countries.

LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2013   06181-004-0451047-02312
Microsoft LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2013

Office Developer Tools - May 2014 Update ENU   06181-004-0451047-02312
Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2013 - May 2014 Update ENU

Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2013   06181-004-0451047-02312
Microsoft Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2013

Visual Basic 2013   06181-004-0451047-02312
Microsoft Visual Basic 2013

Visual C# 2013   06181-004-0451047-02312
Microsoft Visual C# 2013

Visual C++ 2013   06181-004-0451047-02312
Microsoft Visual C++ 2013

Visual F# 2013   06181-004-0451047-02312
Microsoft Visual F# 2013

Visual Studio 2013 Code Analysis Spell Checker   06181-004-0451047-02312
Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2013 Code Analysis Spell Checker

Portions of International CorrectSpell™ spelling correction system © 1993 by Lernout & Hauspie Speech Products N.V. All rights reserved.

The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Third Edition Copyright © 1992 Houghton Mifflin Company. Electronic version licensed from Lernout & Hauspie Speech Products N.V. All rights reserved.

Windows Phone SDK 8.0 - ENU   06181-004-0451047-02312
Windows Phone SDK 8.0 - ENU

ASP.NET and Web Tools   2013.2.50425
Microsoft Web Developer Tools contains the following components:
Support for creating and opening ASP.NET web projects
Browser Link: A communication channel between Visual Studio and browsers
Editor extensions for HTML, CSS, and JavaScript
Page Inspector: Inspection tool for ASP.NET web projects
Scaffolding: A framework for building and running code generators
Server Explorer extensions for Windows Azure Web Sites
Web publishing: Extensions for publishing ASP.NET web projects to hosting providers, on-premises servers, or Windows Azure

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012.2   4.1.21001.0
For additional information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=309563

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.1.20409.0
For additional information, visit http://www.asp.net/

Common Azure Tools   1.1
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Windows Azure Tools.

Microsoft Advertising SDK for Windows Phone   
Microsoft Advertising SDK for Windows Phone
Build 

NuGet Package Manager   2.8.50313.46
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.

PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2
Microsoft Visual Studio extension to visualize aggregated summaries from the PreEmptive Analytics product.

SQL Server Data Tools   12.0.40403.0
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

Windows Azure Mobile Services Tools   1.1
Windows Azure Mobile Services Tools

Windows Azure Tools   2.3
Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 - v2.3.20320.1602

Windows Phone 8.1 SDK Integration   1.0
This package integrates the tools for the Windows Phone 8.1 SDK into the menus and controls of Visual Studio.

Workflow Manager Tools 1.0   1.0
This package contains the necessary Visual Studio integration components for Workflow Manager.
```

---

```
Exception was thrown at line 5121, column 7 in http://localhost:56470/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js
0x800a139e - Błąd czasu wykonywania kodu JavaScript: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown at line 5121, column 7 in http://localhost:56470/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js
0x800a139e - Błąd czasu wykonywania kodu JavaScript: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown at line 5121, column 7 in http://localhost:56470/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js
0x800a139e - Błąd czasu wykonywania kodu JavaScript: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown at line 5121, column 7 in http://localhost:56470/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js
0x800a139e - Błąd czasu wykonywania kodu JavaScript: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown at line 5121, column 7 in http://localhost:56470/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js
0x800a139e - Błąd czasu wykonywania kodu JavaScript: SyntaxError
A first chance exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/8/ROOT-1-130484745632370904): Loaded 'C:\Users\R\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\f8f9d57a\eb864ccb\App_Web_av3asopl.dll'. 
A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in Microsoft.CSharp.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in Microsoft.CSharp.dll
Exception was thrown at line 5108, column 4 in http://localhost:56470/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js
0x800a139e - Błąd czasu wykonywania kodu JavaScript: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown at line 5046, column 7 in http://localhost:56470/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js
0x800a139e - Błąd czasu wykonywania kodu JavaScript: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown at line 37, column 60610 in http://localhost:12285/3e649a4c345742d4b6918e349756f23e/browserLink
0x800a139e - Błąd czasu wykonywania kodu JavaScript: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown at line 5046, column 7 in http://localhost:56470/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js
0x800a139e - Błąd czasu wykonywania kodu JavaScript: SyntaxError
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled Windows then installed VS2013 with Update2 then installed Update3. Bugs are gone(project is the same).

Answer (score 1):

Those are handled exceptions, correct?  If so, you can safely ignore all of the JavaScript Syntax "Errors" in your Output window.  The jQuery team finds it acceptable to use handled Exceptions for logic flow.  Yes, this decision makes debugging your application through VS more difficult.  It clouds up the Output window.

For more information check this [jQuery ticket 14123](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14123).